# Laravel keeps getting the same cache result even if I input different search keyword

Tags: mysql, laravel, caching

I got a api request that has a parameter in it which is projectname. The problem is when I search for example A the results will be A but when I search for B the result is till A even if I search C the result is still the same. I think the cache saved the first results from the first search string. My question is how could I save every results in every search query without getting the same result based on the search query?

Here is my code

```
 public function getRecordDetails(Request $request){

        if(!empty($request->limit)){
            $limit = " LIMIT ".$_REQUEST['limit'];
        }
        else{
            $limit= '';
        }

        if(empty($request->projectname)){
            dd('Field is empty');
        }
        else{

            $data = Cache::rememberForever('results', function () use($request) {
                $result =  DB::connection('mysql2')
                ->table('xp_pn_ura_transactions')
                ->whereRaw(DB::raw("CONCAT(block, ' ', street,' ',project_name,' ', postal_code,'')LIKE '%$request->projectname%' order by STR_TO_DATE(sale_date, '%d-%M-%Y') desc"))
                ->limit($request->limit)
                ->distinct()
                ->get();

                $count =  DB::connection('mysql2')
                ->table('xp_pn_ura_transactions')
                ->whereRaw(DB::raw("CONCAT(block, ' ', street,' ',project_name,' ', postal_code,'')LIKE '%$request->projectname%'"))
                ->count();


                return json_encode(array('count'=>$count,'result'=>$result));
            });

            return $data;
        }
    }
```

PS: This question is based here [How could I cache every api response results in my query in Laravel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59817523/how-could-i-cache-every-api-response-results-in-my-query-in-laravel/59818043#59818043) I answered here but this is different problem based on my answer. Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Laravel find the Cache by the key. You're using `results` as your key.

So no matter how different request you pass. It still can find the cache by `results`.

So it will return the first cache you store in `results`.

```php
$key = "results:".$request->projectname.':' $request->limit;
Cache::rememberForever($key, function () use ($request) {
    ...
}
```

This one will store every different `projectname` you request.

However

#### Problem 1:

There are so many diff possibilities that user can request.
I don't think it is a good idea to store all these cache. If there are not that much, it is ok.

#### Solution:

Or you can use `remember()` instead of `rememberForever()`

```php
$ttl = ????; // Find the appropriate time to expire the cache
$value = Cache::remember($key, $ttl, function () {});
```

#### Problem 2:

There is a `$request->limit` in your cache.

That means if someone insert or delete a record in that table. next time you request with another `limit`, you will face the duplicated records.

#### Solution:

So I think you can clear the cache after you `create` , `update` or `delete` the records.

Comment: I see sir. But I only have a select statement in my api. I only update my api if necessary maybe once a month if i got new records to scrape. Is this okay right?

Comment: I think this is the appropriate answer

Comment: @user001232 it's not a big problem, if you feels too much cache u store. Just set the expired time for the cache.

Answer (score 3):

Because you are using the same cache slug over and over. You should change the cache slug according to the changed input. Adding the `$request` as a use argument to your function will not magically change the cache slug.

In your case, this should work:

```
Cache::rememberForever("results_{$request->projectname}", function () use ($request) {
```

Comment: Okay I will try this also sir. Thanks a lot for this

Answer (score 0):

you should add text value after and before key id like bello

```
Cache::rememberForever('product_'.$product->id.'_key',function ()

});
```